Visual Code Hot Key/s For Exiting Attribute Name
While using visual code for HTML is there a way to exit the parenthesis quicker than using the arrows
Ex
When typing the name "title" is it possible to exit the parenthesis with a key? Just curious as it would make programming faster!

Using the tab key you can exit easily.
